# React native passing data to another screen

Tags: react-native, parameter-passing, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I need to pass data to another screen. This is the code at the Navigation Stack

```
 <Stack.Screen name="MyScreen" component={MyScreen} options={({ route }) => ({ title: 'Profile', url: 'http://www.google.com' })} />
```

In the other screen, this is my code, but I am not able to see the parameters.

```
import { Alert, View, Text, StyleSheet,} from 'react-native';

export default class MyScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        let mydata = navigation.getParam('url', 'http://');
        alert(mydata);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in react-navigation v5

you can set initialParams like this

```
<Stack.Screen
  name = "MyScreen"
  component = {MyScreen}
  initialParams = {{
    myParam: 'Example value from param',
    myAnotherParam: 5
  }}
/>
```

then in your screen's script, you can access myParam or myAnotherParam like this

```
this.props.route.params.myParam // 'Example value from param'

this.props.route.params.myAnotherParam // 5
```